# API KEY missing from x-api-key header

Tags: request, postman, api-key, request-headers

I am a little confused because I successfully wrote the x-api-key but postmant didn't agree with me and sent me this err

A little bit about the task - I need to fetch some info through the Moralis server and get a response list so  I write down the x-api-key for example in query parameter and its work -

https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/nft/0x495f947276749Ce646f68AC8c248420045cb7b5e?chain=eth&format=decimal

but my request doesnt work - {{local}}/assets/my?page=1&address={{address}}
and sent me an error like invalid hex number or missing x-api key ... I spend much time solving it maybe someone has any ideas [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOQLp.png)?